# Booting VM with MaaS

Tags: maas, virtualization

I wondered is it possible to boot VM from MaaS which is also on a VM. I have two VMs on my physical machine, one is MaaS and others should be booted by MaaS. VMs are on ESXi 6.0 and are handled by vSphere Client. I have problems when trying to commission VM node in MaaS i get the message "Failed to power on node...virsh failed with return code 1: Failed to login to virsh console"
I suspect that something might be wrong with power parameters in node settings. When I do "sudo virsh list --all" the list is empty (I've installed libvirt-bin). Can you please tell me which are the correct parameters to include in Power parameters virsh settings and where can I find correct values for these parameters.
If you think that there is some other solution please advise me.

BR,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

most likely it is because your 'maas' user is not a member of the libvirt group. Try adding the user with:

```
sudo adduser maas libvirtd
```

and see if that makes any difference. If not, it may well depend on what version of Ubuntu you are running and/or what version of MAAS you have installed, so please add these to the question!